# How to add continuation backslash or character to MongoDB script

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I need to write a script to create multiple users and roles in MongoDB from the command line..

Below is an example of one of the scripts.

```
mongo $DB --eval "db.createUser({ user: '$USER', pwd: '$PASS', roles: [ { role: '$ROLE', db: '$DB' } ] });"
```

I know in bash, you can simple add back slash to condense a lengthy script

```
mongo $DB --eval \
"db.createUser({ user: '$USER', pwd: '$PASS',\ 
roles: [ { role: '$ROLE', db: '$DB' } ] });"
```

I tried the something similar to bash but the script is treating the slash as a literal string. Any idea how to fix the issue?

Comment: What happens if you remove the `\\`` that is contained within the string, on the second line? ie. `pwd: '$PASS'," \`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with a `space` character present after the `\` character in the second line. The below command will work for you.

```
mongo $DB --eval \
"db.createUser({ user: '$USER', pwd: '$PASS',\
roles: [ { role: '$ROLE', db: '$DB' } ] });"
```